# How to fetch size of file in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have sheet with lot of data in one cell and URLs of documents in next cell. I want to fetch the size of document. Is it possible in Excel?

For example:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Cell A                      | Cell B     |
|------------------------------------------|
| http://m---.com/myfile.txt  |   4kbs     |
|------------------------------------------|
| http://m---.com/myfile.txt  |   10kbs    |
|------------------------------------------|
| http://m---.com/myfile.doc  |  104kbs    |
|------------------------------------------|
| http://m---.com/myfile.jpg  |   102kbs   |
|------------------------------------------|
```

I just have URL lists in column `A` and I want to have file size in column `B`.

I tried VBA code for this but its not working. One more thing, I just got this code from internet and its not mine, but it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
print file path Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Path 'print size Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Size
```

Comment: Here you have an example of a similar case. You can use as a reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883237/vba-excel-function-for-returning-file-size-in-byte

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please share with us what you have already attempted (include any formulas or code)?

Comment: hi i tried vba code for this but its not working . one thing more i just got this code from internet and its not mine . but it was not help me..  here is code ' 'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Path
    'print size
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Size'

Comment: Is the question really unclear to someone, or are close votes intended to punish the asker for the lack of effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this code in a new module on your Excel file and run the `Tester` function to test it out.

For testing, replace the URL in the `Tester` function with a URL of your own to test.

```
Sub Tester()
MsgBox FileSize("https://www.google.com/images/logo.png")
End Sub

Function FileSize(sURL As String)
Dim oXHTTP As Object
Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", sURL, False
oXHTTP.send
If oXHTTP.Status = 200 Then
FileSize = oXHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")
Else
FileSize = -1
End If
End Function
```

Once this is pasted in a module in your Excel fille, you can use it through VBA as shown in the `Tester` function or you can use it as below:

If column `A` contains all the URLs, and you want to show the file size in column `B`, type this in cell `B1` and drag it down:

```
=FileSize(A1)
```

The above will give the file size in bytes. If you want to display the file size in kilo bytes rounded to 2 decimal places and have "KB" displayed next to the number, you can update the following line of code:

```
FileSize = oXHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")
```

to the new one below:

```
FileSize = CStr(Round(oXHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") / 1024, 2)) + " KB"
```

Comment: thanks for help , but problem is that i dont have files in folder my files on server and in Cell A i have lot of urls . can you help me in this how i use this code for urls

Comment: pls see info in updated answer